# Need to redirect 301 a URL in .htaccess file but it adds extra http//?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**I am trying to redirect /abc.html to /abc.php** but when I did it gives an **extra http//** and page is not working like **http//www.example.de/abc.php** don't know from where this HTTP comes.

note: website is not with ssl so domain name is http://example.de

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectPermanent /tour.html /tour.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##To serve home page link.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.html/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Christinaleonel, could you please do mention sample of url for which you are getting error?

Comment: `Internal Server Error` my website name is die-malireise.de it is not secured https, it is http  for now

Comment: @Christinaleonel, ok, could you please confirm if you are hitting link like: `http://localhost:80/test.html` etc?

Comment: No it is live website on server now, whenever it tried to access `http//example.de/xyz.html` it should redirect to `http//example.de/xyz.php` but it add extra http and shows `http://http//www.example.de/xyz.php`

Comment: @Christinaleonel, my rules should work, do you have any other rules in your htaccess file? OR do you have any other htaccess rule files?

Comment: no nothing also I have not used anything my files contains some lines  - `RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond ^([^.]*)\.html/?$ $1.php [NC,L]`  this only nothing else then this

Comment: @Christinaleonel, I apologies, there was a typo in rules(from my side). I have fixed it now, could you please do check now new rules(edited them now) and let me know how it goes?

Comment: hey @ravindersingh31 I check now my home page says not found always why? but when i removed your code website works fine

Comment: @Christinaleonel, oh ok, then could you please do check my updated rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @Christinaleonel, ok so from which file you want your home page to be served in backend? Eg--> index.php etc

Comment: yes index.php, also due to your .htaccess code show php code in inspect element

Comment: @Christinaleonel, oh ok sure. Could you please do use my updated Rules once and let me know if this helps you? Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Thank you its perfect

Comment: @Christinaleonel, your welcome cheers and happy learning. Keep posting good questions and answers 